# What does the DoFixture's check function expect as input?

Tags: fitnesse, dbfit

I am going crazy here so bear with me... 
We are using Fitnesse (with DbFit framework / based on FIT) to automatise some tests in which we run some shell commands. We have a fixture which connects to the linux server, runs the command and returns the results (see bellow)

```
class SSHConnection {

private static final String DEFAULT_KEY = "~/.ssh/id_rsa";
private String host;
private String password;
private int port;
private String privateKey;
private Session session;
private String user;

/** Creates a JSch object and open a connection with a remote server using the values set in the class variables.
 */
public void connect() {.........}


/**
 * Executes a command in the remote server using the connection opened by connect().
 * @param command command to execute in the remote server
 * @return the output result of the command as String
 */
public String execute(String command) {
    logger.info("Executing command: " + command);

    String result;

    try {
        ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        channelExec.setCommand(command);

        // Open exec channel
        channelExec.connect();

        InputStream stream = channelExec.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line).append("\n");
        }

        result = output.toString();

        // Close exec channel
        channelExec.disconnect();

        logger.debug("Command executed successfully: " + result);

    } catch (JSchException | IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error executing command: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
    return result;
}}
```

So I'm expecting whatever get's displayed on the shell after running the command to be returned (as a string) and compared to whatever my test in fitnesse requires.

Fitnesse catches the results but always fails the comparison and I don't know why (I only added the sed command to remove the whitespaces, but still the comparison fails!!

I feel like Fitnesse is mocking me showing me the same value for expected, actual and diff. 
Is it and encoding issue? is it a java type issue? How does check work?

[image]

Edit: I even tried running the shell command twice and saving the result the first time and then set it as the expected results. It still fails.

```
 |set | VarAddress | run command | cat AddressNoSpaces.txt |
 |check| run command | cat AddressNoSpaces.txt | @{VarAddress} |
```

[image]

Comment: Further more, I even tried to run the shell command twice and saving the results in a variable the first time and then set it as an expected result. IT STILL FAILS!! 
|set | VarAddress | run command | cat AddressNoSpaces.txt |
|check| run command | cat AddressNoSpaces.txt | @{VarAddress} |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK problem solved, it seems that the shell command output added a new line char which fitnesse did not like. I changed that java class to strip the return value from it's last char and it's working.